# Why UIBezierPath's corners are transparent?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibezierpath

I want to make my TopLeft and TopRight corners with corner radius. It works with this code:

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = self.name.frame
rectShape.position = self.name.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.name.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .TopLeft | .TopRight, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).CGPath
rectShape.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

self.name.layer.mask = rectShape
```

but it makes the corners transparent, like this:

[image]

How can I make them visible?

Comment: If you create the bezierpath first into a variable and set a breakpoint you will be able to inspect the shape of the path.

Comment: what is self.name here.

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan UITextView

Comment: @Fogmeister i do not use any framework

Comment: My mistake. I failed to see it in the docs. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Bcs it's just a mask, your layer still square. There are many ways to do it, for example, you can paint your own layer and add it as sublayer. This properties should help you:

```
layer.fillColor = LAYER_COLOR.CGColor;
layer.strokeColor = LAYER_BORDER_COLOR.CGColor;
layer.lineWidth = LAYER_BORDER_WIDTH;
layer.opacity = LAYER_OPACITY;
```

Comment: LOL, didn't spot that one. Nice answer

Comment: Like this: `rectShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;`? it doesn't work

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade Did you set lineWidth? Did you insert layer above some other opaque layers? I set this properties, then set path property and add sublayer - it's work perfect

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade did you read my answer? You still using mask, DON'T use it, just add sublayer to self.name.layer

Comment: but in this `self.name.layer = rectShape` case it prints me `Cannot assign to the result of this expression`

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade You are hopeless, my friend :) read documentation [addSublayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/addSublayer:)